# How to set a variable keyword in a Django model field?

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    street                  = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300, verbose_name='Straat')
    house_number            = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10,        verbose_name='Huisnummer')
    zipcode                 = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300, verbose_name='Postcode')
    city                    = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300, verbose_name='Stad')
```

However, for some Models that use this Address Model, I want the blank=True be blank=False.
How can I specify this upon creation of the model?
This didnt work:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    blank = False
    street                  = models.CharField(blank=blank, max_length=300, verbose_name='Straat')
    house_number            = models.CharField(blank=blank, max_length=10,        verbose_name='Huisnummer')
    zipcode                 = models.CharField(blank=blank, max_length=300, verbose_name='Postcode')
    city                    = models.CharField(blank=blank, max_length=300, verbose_name='Stad')

#Create
Address(blank=True)
```

Comment: What does "for some Models that use this Address Model" mean?

Comment: That means that I have for instance a Customer model that has a Many-to-many field for Address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank) explains, `blank` is purely for validation purposes. It is not enforced except when doing model or form validation. So if you need to allow blank fields in an address form under certain circumstances, you can simply override your form field accordingly (remember in form fields, use `required` instead of `blank`):

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    street = forms.TextField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Address
```